# How to mark articles as read?

Tags: posts, cookies

I have a normal Link:

```
<a href="/article-1"><span class="visited-circle"></span>article 1</a>
```

and when someone have visited this article so i changed the color in CSS:

```
a:visited .visited-circle {
  background-color: green;
}
```

But I think that is not so perfect. I want that the visitor can mark this article as read. Has someone an idea how I can realize this?

Comment: Does this link or its container have any class or id that points to the post ID rather than providing the post link only? I mean I would store the viewed posts in a cookie and check for them later to add the `visited-circle` className..

Comment: Mark as read? For how long? Until refresh? Session? Forever? There's not enough information.

Comment: Do you want to permanently store the data of which post is read by which user ?

Comment: Yes a button who can a user mark the article as read. I think the solutions login or cookie from Mark Kaplun and Samuel Elh sounds good.

Comment: It may be a lot easier to change the perspective slightly up and check if the article has been "visited".  And if so, simply wire up Google Analytics to get a running count on pages viewed.  By doing so, you keep WordPress focusing on it's core functionality and rely on a third-party tool that will give you robust results.  Also, you can always concatenate user data to a GA event handler, which goes back to your GA dashboard.  And that's only the beginning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a truly full solution you need to have all the users to have an account (or create one when marking as read) and you associate in the DB the user with the posts that he read and then style each link appropriately. To implement this you can look for inspiration in plugins that add a review or other like/ranking functionality. The problem with this approach is that users need to have some other incentive to login otherwise they will probably not use the functionality.

The less robust option (but easier to implement) is to store the list of the posts read in long term cookie, and style the links based on the values in the cookie. The problem with this approach is that the cookies are local to a specific device and a user might end up with fragmented "reading list" between all the devices that he uses